# Assigning edge_keys to networkx multigraph using from_pandas_edgelist function returns errors

Tags: python, networkx, edge-list

I am trying to recreate the following script from the [networkx documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html?highlight=from_pandas#networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist):

```
edges = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "source": [0, 1, 2, 0],
    "target": [2, 2, 3, 2],
    "my_edge_key": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    "weight": [3, 4, 5, 6],
    "color": ["red", "blue", "blue", "blue"],
})
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
edges,
edge_key="my_edge_key",
edge_attr=["weight", "color"],
create_using=nx.MultiGraph(),)
```

When I do this, instead of getting the expected graph, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: from_pandas_edgelist() got an unexpected keyword argument 'edge_key'
```

I have tried running it after removing the *edge_key="my_edge_key",* part and the graph is generated just fine.
But the thing is, I am working on a large multigraph with edges having the same start and end node pairs. I need to assign keys to my graph edges because I plan to remove particular edges by their keys for the graph that I am working on. So I was wondering, if I was doing something wrong in assigning the edge keys. Or is this an outdated function and there is now a better way to do this? If so, could someone please direct me?

Comment: Which `networkx` version are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The networkx version I am running is 2.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `networkx` to be able to use the `edge_key` parameter. As you can see [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/fd0ecd22723cb30a365511d324841a85caad589c/networkx/convert_matrix.py#L199) the version 2.4 did not had this parameter. In contrast the latest version (as you have also seen in the docs) has the parameter, see [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/1e48dad5c6038b549d7a4a01f190ffd3765eb913/networkx/convert_matrix.py#L217).